# how can we create partials in active admin for index panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to create a partials to render some data in index panel for different namespaces for DRY

I am currently writing

```
 index do
    render 'index', user: :user    
 end
//_index.html.arb
column :id
column 'Customer Name', :name
column :mobile
column :recipient_number    
column :cash_in_hand do |customer|
  number_to_currency(customer.cash_in_hand, unit: "\u20B9", precision: 2)
end
column "Due Balance" do |customer|      
  number_to_currency(customer.due_balance, unit: "\u20B9", precision: 2)
end
actions
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a partial to render that data exactly like this

```
# app/admin/some_class.rb
index do
  render 'admin/index', context: self    
end
```

You probably will want to create a folder called 'admin' in views for these types of partials ...

```
# app/views/admin/_index.html.erb
<% context.instance_eval do
  column :id
  column 'Customer Name', :name
  column :mobile
  column :recipient_number    
  column :cash_in_hand do |customer|
    number_to_currency(customer.cash_in_hand, unit: "\u20B9", precision: 2)
  end
  column "Due Balance" do |customer|      
    number_to_currency(customer.due_balance, unit: "\u20B9", precision: 2)
  end
  actions
end %>
```

> I can confirm this works with .erb extention file and .haml but no guaranteeing others

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I would prefer to keep the partial under `app/admin/partials` instead of `app/views/admin`.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in Rails 6 with:

```
#app/admin/some_class.rb
index do
  render partial: 'active_admin/index', locals:{context: self}
end
```

and

```
#app/views/active_admin/_index.html.arb
context.instance_eval do
  selectable_column
  id_column
  column :some_attribute
  actions
end
```

This also satisfies locating the file in a shared place not specific to the admin/ space. It's useful because I have AA running with two separate user models and I often want to share the same code for index, show, etc with minor differences.

If needed, additional key-values can be passed in the locals hash for minor customization of the results.